# Streaming videos via Amazon CloudFront CDN

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda

I am following this blog but after performing Step 3 – Upload video to S3 and trigger HLS encoding it should generate HLS/ folder in my bucket and within that folder no folder with the video filename, appended with a date string. So please help me or provide latest blog update.

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/streaming-videos-to-mobile-app-users-via-amazon-cloudfront-cdn/

Any help will be appreciable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was also stuck on this issue for couple of hours. After that got a solution that, CloudFront Distribution takes minimum 20 minutes to get created. Also, check the below link for the same.

https://medium.com/@kout.petr/using-aws-for-video-streaming-7a46264fcfb6